# Trying to debug int arrays

Tags: java, arrays, debugging, netbeans-8

I'm trying to put together a little game concept in java, and have encountered a strange problem; int arrays don't seem to be storing any values in certain parts of my code!
(Using netbeans 8.2)
I suspect it is something small and tedious that I have missed.
This is the constructor for a basic Creature. See the "addTrait" method? That is the focus.

```
public Creature(String inputname)
{
    if(DEBUG>0){System.out.println("DEBUG: CREATURE ");}

    creaturename = inputname;
    size = 1;
    population = 1;

    addTrait(new Trait("TEST",0,new int[]{4,4,4,4,4,4}),0);
    addTrait(new Trait("EMPTY",0,new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0}),1);
    addTrait(new Trait("EMPTY",0,new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0}),2);

}
```

This is the method in the Creature class.

```
public void addTrait(Trait newtrait, int slotnum)
{
    myTraits[slotnum] = newtrait;

    if(DEBUG>0){System.out.println("DEBUG: CREATURE > "
            + "addTrait > myTraits["+slotnum+"].getName() = "+
            myTraits[slotnum].getName());}


        for(int k=0;6>k;k++)
        {
            System.out.println("DEBUG: CREATURE > "
            + "addTrait > myTraits["+slotnum+"].getEffects()["+k+"] = "+
            myTraits[slotnum].getEffects()[k]);
        }

        System.out.println();
}
```

In my driver class, I attempt to add the "Sharp Eyesight" trait to my test creature.

```
public class EvoDriver {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // initilize TraitList  
    TraitList myTraits = new TraitList();

    // initilize Creature

    Creature player1 = new Creature("Dragon Bear");

    player1.addPop();
    player1.addPop();
    player1.growSize();

    // add specific trait

    //player1.addTrait(myTraits.getTrait("Carnivore"), 0);
    player1.addTrait(myTraits.getTrait("Sharp Eyesight"), 1);
    //player1.addTrait(myTraits.getTrait("Fire Breath"), 2);

    //force update
    player1.updateStats();
    //print creature
    player1.printCreature();



}
```

This is the constructor for a trait.

```
public Trait(String newname, int fv, int[] effects)
{
    if(DEBUG>0){System.out.println("DEBUG: TRAIT");}

    traitname = newname;
    feedvalue = fv;

    //handle effects
    effects[0] = feedertype;
    effects[1] = size;
    effects[2] = power;
    effects[3] = stealth;
    effects[4] = senses;
    effects[5] = dangerous;

    if(DEBUG>0){System.out.println("DEBUG: TRAIT > traitname = "+traitname);}
    if(DEBUG>0){System.out.println("DEBUG: TRAIT > senses = "+senses);}

}
```

I have a class that is supposed to handle initiating the stat boosts for each trait called TraitList. It holds all the data for each trait. However, when the method "getEffects" is called, the result is always 0!

```
public class TraitList {

//DEBUG MODE 
final int DEBUG = 1;



Trait[] allTraits = {new Trait("EMPTY",0,new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0})};

// **** Constructors ****

/*                              HINTS
____________________________________________________________________________
effects[0] = feedertype;
effects[1] = size;
effects[2] = power;
effects[3] = stealth;
effects[4] = senses;
effects[5] = dangerous;
*/


public TraitList()
{

    if(DEBUG>0){System.out.println("DEBUG: TRAITLIST ");}



    boolean[] special = new boolean[2];
    special[0] = false; //Alert the Herd
    special[1] = false; //Pack Tactics

    //add effects to list

    // Sharp Eyesight; increases Senses by 3

    //feedertype;
    //size;
    //power;
    //stealth;
    //senses;
    //dangerous;
    addTrait(new Trait("Sharp Eyesight", 2, new int[]{0,0,0,0,3,0} )
            .setDesc("Helps detect other creatures!"));

    // Camouflage; increases Stealth by 3

    addTrait(new Trait("Camouflage", 0, new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0}));

    // Alert the Herd; increases Senses by Population number
    addTrait(new Trait("Alert the Herd", 0, special));

    // Pack Tactics; increases Power by Population number
    addTrait(new Trait("Pack Tactics", 0, special));

    // Carnivore; creature can only eat meat; Senses +1, Stealth +1

    addTrait(new Trait("Carnivore", -1, new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0}));

    // Omnivore; creature can eat meat and plants

    addTrait(new Trait("Omnivore", -5, new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0}));

    // Horns; increases Dangerous by 1

    addTrait(new Trait("Horns", 0, new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0})); 

    // Fire Breath; increases Dangerous by 3, increases Power by 3; feed 10

    addTrait(new Trait("Fire Breath", 10, new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0}));
}

// **** Methods ****

public void addTrait(Trait newtrait)
{
    // create temp array
    Trait[] temp = new Trait[1]; 
    temp[0] = newtrait;
    Trait[] newtemp = new Trait[allTraits.length+1];
    for (int k=0; allTraits.length>k;k++)
    {
        newtemp[k] = allTraits[k];
    }   
    newtemp[allTraits.length] = temp[0];

    allTraits = newtemp;   

}

public Trait getRandomTrait() // to do
{
    return null;
}

public int getTraitIndex(String searchname)//returns 0 if not found
{

    for(int k=0;allTraits.length>k;k++)
    {
        if(DEBUG>0)
        {System.out.println("DEBUG: TRAITLIST > getTraitIndex > k = "+k);}

        if(DEBUG>0)
        {System.out.println("DEBUG: TRAITLIST > getTraitIndex > "
                + "allTraits[k].getName() = "+allTraits[k].getName());}

        if(searchname.equalsIgnoreCase(allTraits[k].getName()))
        {
            return k;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("ERROR IN TraitList > getTraitIndex! TRAIT " 
            + searchname +" DOES NOT EXIST!");
    return 0;
}

public Trait getTrait(String name)//returns EMPTY trait if not found
{
    return allTraits[getTraitIndex(name)];
}
```

}

I don't know how clear I've been, but I would very much appreciate any hints, advice, hell I'd take a useful insult pointing out my stupid mistakes. I will attach my debug output.

```
run:
DEBUG: TRAIT
DEBUG: TRAIT > traitname = EMPTY
DEBUG: TRAIT > senses = 0
DEBUG: TRAITLIST 
DEBUG: TRAIT
DEBUG: TRAIT > traitname = Sharp Eyesight
DEBUG: TRAIT > senses = 0
DEBUG: TRAIT
DEBUG: TRAIT > traitname = Camouflage
DEBUG: TRAIT > senses = 0
DEBUG: TRAIT
DEBUG: TRAIT > traitname = Carnivore
DEBUG: TRAIT > senses = 0
DEBUG: TRAIT
DEBUG: TRAIT > traitname = Omnivore
DEBUG: TRAIT > senses = 0
DEBUG: TRAIT
DEBUG: TRAIT > traitname = Horns
DEBUG: TRAIT > senses = 0
DEBUG: TRAIT
DEBUG: TRAIT > traitname = Fire Breath
DEBUG: TRAIT > senses = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE 
DEBUG: TRAIT
DEBUG: TRAIT > traitname = TEST
DEBUG: TRAIT > senses = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[0].getName() = TEST
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[0].getEffects()[0] = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[0].getEffects()[1] = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[0].getEffects()[2] = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[0].getEffects()[3] = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[0].getEffects()[4] = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[0].getEffects()[5] = 0

DEBUG: TRAIT
DEBUG: TRAIT > traitname = EMPTY
DEBUG: TRAIT > senses = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[1].getName() = EMPTY
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[1].getEffects()[0] = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[1].getEffects()[1] = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[1].getEffects()[2] = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[1].getEffects()[3] = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[1].getEffects()[4] = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[1].getEffects()[5] = 0

DEBUG: TRAIT
DEBUG: TRAIT > traitname = EMPTY
DEBUG: TRAIT > senses = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[2].getName() = EMPTY
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[2].getEffects()[0] = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[2].getEffects()[1] = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[2].getEffects()[2] = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[2].getEffects()[3] = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[2].getEffects()[4] = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[2].getEffects()[5] = 0

DEBUG: TRAITLIST > getTraitIndex > k = 0
DEBUG: TRAITLIST > getTraitIndex > allTraits[k].getName() = EMPTY
DEBUG: TRAITLIST > getTraitIndex > k = 1
DEBUG: TRAITLIST > getTraitIndex > allTraits[k].getName() = Sharp Eyesight
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[1].getName() = Sharp Eyesight
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[1].getEffects()[0] = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[1].getEffects()[1] = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[1].getEffects()[2] = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[1].getEffects()[3] = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[1].getEffects()[4] = 0
DEBUG: CREATURE > addTrait > myTraits[1].getEffects()[5] = 0

_________________________________________________
Dragon Bear (Pop: 3)
[Herbivore]
_________________________________________________
Size: 2
Power: 2
Stealth: 0
Senses: 0
Dangerous: 0
_________________________________________________
Trait 1: TEST
 ~ {  }
Trait 2: Sharp Eyesight
 ~ { Helps detect other creatures! }
Trait 3: EMPTY
 ~ {  }
_________________________________________________
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

If no solution can be found, I'll probably start over from scratch. (I'll reuse bits of working code of course!)

Comment: Please post the whole `Trait` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you are constructor, you are re-assigning the values of effects. This is potential problem.

```
effects[0] = feedertype;
effects[1] = size;
effects[2] = power;
effects[3] = stealth;
effects[4] = senses;
effects[5] = dangerous;
```